# How to get the xtype of an instantiated component?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Suppose I have an component's instance but I don't know what it is. Is there a convenient way to get the xtype of this component?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getXType) all *components* (all types of *Ext JS* objects with an `xtype` I guess) inherits a method `getXType()`, which you can use like in the following:

```
var t = new Ext.form.TextField();
alert(t.getXType());  // alerts 'textfield'
```

Comment: Oops...I just scanned the api of Ext.Component but failed to find it...Thanks.